# How should I store vacuum-sealed sliced salami?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, salami

I had a whole Genoa salami that I sliced into very thin slices. I would like to save the remaining meat for consumption later, so I separated them into approximately 1-pound bags and vacuum-sealed them for storage.

How should I store the bagged salami, and how long can I expect it to keep? The original salami was rated to be shelf-stable with no refrigeration for about 8 months judging by the date on the label, but I'm not sure how that changes once it is sliced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the vacuum sealed bags in the refrigerator or the freezer.  It would have been better to leave the salami whole for long term storage, simply to reduce the impact of oxidation and flavor loss. The only other thing that changes with slicing is the potential that you contaminated it, either by touching it or because your equipment was not clean.   If this is the case, you will observe mold forming on the salami.  If that happens, discard.  Otherwise, the only worry you have is flavor loss.  Frozen, I would say you have several months.  Refrigerated, you'll experience flavor changes after a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I will probably freeze it then; I was concerned about flavor loss with freezing, as I've never frozen salami before. I had to slice it all today as I don't usually have access to a slicer, so I will keep an eye out for the contamination you pointed out.

Comment: @JasonR Freezing should also prevent mold growth, even if you contaminated it.

Comment: @JasonR high-fat-content items generally freeze well, as there is a reduced opportunity for dehydration and cell wall breakdown, which occurs as your freezer's temperature cycles.